Undefined Symbol To Static Const Member Variable in std::pair Construction
When populating an unordered map of int pairs, creating a std::pair object with a static const class member seems to cause an undefined symbol error, but only in the std::pair constructor call. If I replace the use of the static const member, with a variable set by that member the build succeeds.
Simple test to demonstrate the issue:
This produces an undefined symbol: Test::Command error
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>

class Test {
 public:
 static const int Command = 3;   
};

int main()
{
    
    std::unordered_map<int, int> test_map;
    
    test_map.insert(std::pair(Test::Command, 2));
  
  return 0;
}

However, replacing the Test::Command with the following:
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>

class Test {
 public:
 static const int Command = 3;   
};

int main()
{
    
    std::unordered_map<int, int> test_map;
    int test = Test::Command;
    test_map.insert(std::pair(test, 2));
  
  return 0;
}

results in a successful build.

Please add the full error message to the question.

static const int Command = 3; declares Test::Command, and provides it a value of = 3, but does not define it.  Hence the undefined symbol error.

This is the usual declaration versus definition problem of static member variables. The solution, as posted by Remy Lebeau (and many others here), is to either split up the declaration and definition (the "old" way) or make it an inline definition. Also, any decent beginners book or tutorial should have told you about it.

I can reproduce the same error using the exact code you have shown:
https://onlinegdb.com/CKY2AbU6O
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc0eyRLY.o: warning: relocation against `_ZN4Test7CommandE' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc0eyRLY.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `Test::Command'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The error goes away when I add inline or constexpr (which is implicitly inline) to the declaration of Command, eg:
class Test {
 public:
  inline static const int Command = 3;   
  // or:
  // static constexpr int Command = 3;   
};

See: Inline static const vs static const variable
The error also goes away if I split the declaration and initialization of Command, eg:
class Test {
 public:
 static const int Command;
};
...
const int Test::Command = 3;

